# How do I get the cURL responses for different pages?

Tags: python, curl, scrapy

I'm working on a small data scraping project and would like to get all the jobs from the website `https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/`. The jobs are loaded as POST request. I can go in the individual pages and get the cURL of the `POST` requests and play in the terminal and get some `JSON`. The JSON I get have the  following format (I provided what I get from the `Firefox` `network tab`, cURL also provides the same in the terminal),

[image]

Now, all I need what's inside the `html tag` and I can iterate over the `href`s on that respective pages using the code snippet,

```
    html = data['html']
    selector = scrapy.Selector(text=data['html'], type="html")
    hrefs = selector.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
    for href in hrefs: 
        // some code
```

I use `scrapy` and the convention is to use `start_urls` list for scraping the pages and then, I can put all the codes inside the `parse` function the way I like.

Here is another issue. In the respective website, there are 17 pages and link of the 1st page is `https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/` and rest of the pages have the same link `https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/#s=1`. So, you can\'t really tell which page you are in based on the link: can be 3 or 9 I just don\'t know.

To summarize the question, I would I get this `html = data['html']` value for all the 17 pages using Python where I have only 2 web links: `https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/`  and `https://www.germanystartupjobs.com/#s=1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `POST`-tab in your network panel you should see different parameters for the request. The page you're on is in this tab.

You can pass this parameter in your request (so in your `yield scrapy.Request`) so that you loop over the page numbers, passing it in your request. For example you could do one request do get the maximum page numbers (`max_num_pages` in the JSON-object) and then pass the page numbers incrementally until you requested every one of them.

Check out the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) on requests.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try and get back to you soon. If this works out, I will accept this answer. Up voted for now as it seems good answer

Comment: Hello, could you please provide me the code for looping over all the pages? I still couldn't make it work properly.